# select data having same id

Tags: sql, having-clause

```
id   idtest  result
1      1        2
1      2        1
1      3        2
2      1        2
2      2        1
2      3        1
3      1        1
3      2        2
3      3        1
```

Would like to get all the rows with the same IDs that matches the condition.
For example: get all the rows with the same id where (idTest=2 and result=1) and (idTest=3 and result=2)

result:

```
id   idtest  result
1      1        2
1      2        1
1      3        2
```

What would be the query???
Thanks!

Comment: @EmmadKareem: no, `select distinct` applies to the entire fieldset. it's not `select distinct(id), any(idtest), any(result)`, it's `select distinct(id, idtest, result)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 and (result = 1 OR result = 2)
```

How about his:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table WHERE (idTest = 2 OR idTest = 3) AND (result=1 OR result=2)
```

Comment: wouldnt this give you the records if only one of the records were found.  I think OP wanted the records where both existed

Comment: @user1221684 First SELECT will return what the OP put as result: in the question. 2nd SELECT will return 6 rows, idtest 2 or 3, and result 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

ID test res

1    1      2

1    2      1

1    3      2

2    1      1

2    2      2

2    3      2

3    1      1

3    2      2

3    3      1

Sorry. This would be my table. and Would like to get all the rows with the same IDs that matches the condition. For example: get all the rows with the same id where (test=2 and res=1) and (test=3 and res=2)

Result:

ID test res

1    1      2

1    2      1

1    3      2

What would be the query in order to get the three rows ?? Thanks!

Comment: If you have more information, then please edit your question instead of "answering" it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want all rows for id's that have rows with that particular combination. What about:

```
with ids as (
   select id
   from mytable
   where (idTest=2 and result=1) or (idTest=3 and result=2)
   group by id
   having count(id) = 2
)
select mytable.* from mytable
inner join ids
  on ids.id = mytable.id
```

This gets a list of id's where both conditions apply, and then gets all rows for those id's.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df893/4)

Comment: would say `having count(*) > 1` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id, idTest, result
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
   WHERE t.id = t2.id 
     AND(
        ( t2.idTest=2 AND t2.result=1 )
       OR
        ( t2.idTest=3 AND t2.result=2 )
     )
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0cec1/3/0)</kbd>

**Update**: result is different:

```
id  idTest  result
1     1     2
1     2     1  <-- satisfies your condition
1     3     2  <-- satisfies your condition
2     1     2
2     2     1  <-- satisfies your condition
2     3     1
```

So either my understanding was incorrect or your expected result. I have also all ID=2 because the second id-2 row matches the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table t1
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = t1.id AND idtest = 2 AND result = 1)
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = t1.id AND idtest = 3 AND result = 2)
```

Just keep adding more `AND EXISTS` if you need more

Or you can use `IN` if it makes more sense to you

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table
WHERE   id IN (SELECT id from table where idtest = 2 and result = 1)
        AND id IN (SELECT id from table where idtest = 3 and result = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

do you need a method that treats the condition(s) in a generic way, like if they're values in another table?  Or do you only need a way to pull results of two independent conditions?

If the latter, then this should work:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  (SELECT   id 
   FROM tbl 
   WHERE    idTest=2 AND RESULT=1) cond1 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT   id 
   FROM tbl 
   WHERE    idTest=3 AND RESULT=2)  cond2   ON
cond1.id = cond2.id
```

otherwise, if your conditions are generic and stored in a table, you'd need something like:

```
SELECT
id
FROM
(SELECT id
FROM    tbl FULL OUTER JOIN conditions c
WHERE   c.isUseMe = 1 AND c.SEQ = 1 AND idTest=c.idTestVal AND result=c.resultVal) cond1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT id
FROM    tbl FULL OUTER JOIN conditions c
WHERE   c.isUseMe = 1 AND c.SEQ = 2 AND idTest=c.idTestVal AND result=c.resultVal)  cond2   ON
cond1.id = cond2.id
```

if the 4 values are passed in as parameters, you'd need something like:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  (SELECT   id
   FROM tbl 
   WHERE     idTest=@idTestVal1 AND result=@resultVal1) cond1 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT   id
   FROM tbl 
   WHERE     idTest=@idTestVal2 AND result=@resultVal2)  cond2  ON
  cond1.id = cond2.id
```